# Converting a double to a std::string without scientific notation

Tags: c++, formatting, floating-point

**Problem**

I need to convert a double to a `std::string` which contains no scientific notation and no unnecessary fillers.

Using `std::fixed` with `iostream` yielded ugly results - extra fillers (0's).  The closest working code I could get was to using `sprintf("%g",...)` and then dealing with exponentials, should they appear (beyond 6 places).

I am looking for improvements in **robustness** or **clarity/simplicity** in the implementation.

**Details/Elaboration (addition)**

I realize that the conversion between `double` and `std::string` and back can be expected to be lossy.  So I am not looking for an implementation that works for all cases.  For example, I don't expect to be able to convert `"0.2000"` to `double` and then get the same back (getting `"0.2"` back would be fine).  Similarly with `"+0.2000"`: getting `"0.2"` back is ok.

I have attempted solutions involving `sprintf("%g",...)`, but the result is automatic conversion to scientific notation when we go beyond six significant digits.  There appears to be no way to configure that setting.  Alternatively, `sprintf("%f",...)` requires that we manually set or calculate the exact precision that we want - which I don't know how to do if that information is lost inside a `double`.  Note that what I have found here seems to equally apply to most simple solutions involving  `std::iostream` and `std::fixed`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <string>
#include <cassert>

static std::string
to_string( double d )
{
  char s[64];
  sprintf( s, "%g", d );

  char* e = std::strchr( s, 'e' );
  if ( e==nullptr )
    return s;
  char* p = std::strchr( s, '.' );

  // eg 2.4e-07
  int exp   = atoi( e+1 );   // -7
  int extra = 0;

  // snip period eg 24
  if ( p!=nullptr ) {
    extra = e-p-1;
    memmove( p, p + 1, strlen(s) - (p-s));
  }

  int coeff = atoi( s );
  // std::cerr << "DEBUG  = " << s << " coeff = " << coeff << " exp = " << exp << "\n";
  if ( exp<0 ) {
    sprintf( s, "0.%0*d", -exp+extra, coeff);
    return s;
  }

  // eg 7.3e+09
  sprintf( s, "%d%0*d", coeff, exp-extra, 0 );
  return s;
}

static void
test_string_conversion( std::string const& s )
{
    assert( to_string( atof( s.c_str() ))==s );
}

int main()
{
   test_string_conversion( "1.5203" );
   test_string_conversion( "-1.025" );
   test_string_conversion( "3.1415" );
   test_string_conversion( "-38271" );
   test_string_conversion( "0.8382" );
   test_string_conversion( "-0.8382" );
   test_string_conversion( "7" );
   test_string_conversion( "-3" );
   test_string_conversion( "0.0000024" );
   test_string_conversion( "7300000000" );
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: `improvements in robustness or clarity/simplicity`:  Yes all this can be done by simply using the standard library. The problem I have is that I don't understand your requirements. In most you are only printing to 4 decimal places `1.5203` while others you are printing to seven `0.0000024` which is it that you want?

Comment: Your problem comes down to representation. If you have a fractional number where the last digit is not 5 you will not be able to represent it exactly in a double and thus you can print out many many decimal places.

Comment: @LokiAstari From a non-technical person's perspective, as much as possible, I want an inverse function to `atof()`.  I realize that there are many hairy details in precision, binary representation, lossy conversions, etc...  ...and yet, `sprintf( "%g" )` seems to be get it mostly right most of the time (aside from extraneous zeros which I try to deal with).

Comment: Also note: `operator<<` standard behavior when passed a double is to use the equivelant of `%g` formatting. See n3797 Section: 22.4.2.2.2 [facet.num.put.virtuals]

Comment: There is no inverse to `atof()` as you point out the conversion is not exact. What you are asking for is `std::cout << aDoubleValue`. Unless you want to specify what you want more exactly the rest is meaningless.

Comment: @LokiAstari As I mentioned in another comment below, the headache to `%g`, in general, appears to be the need to specify a `setprecision` and/or `setf` (or `%x.yg`)- that's where I ran into a wall.  I totally realize that an exact implementation is not possible (which I'm sure is why a standard implementation isn't out there).  I am just looking for a pretty-good implementation (I expect there to be edge cases where the conversion will fail).

Comment: The problem is that `%g` is either `%e` or `%f` (it picks the shortest one). I think what you are after is just `%f` in C++ this is achieved with `std::fixed`

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned in the comments of the other answer, your decimal floating point numbers are stored as binary and rarely have finite representations.

If you simply want code that passes your test I would mention that it is much easier to remove padding from `std::fixed` than it is to expand the scientific notation.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <limits>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cassert>
#include <cstddef>

static std::string to_string(double d)
{
    std::ostringstream oss;
    oss.precision(std::numeric_limits<double>::digits10);
    oss << std::fixed << d;
    std::string str = oss.str();

    // Remove padding
    // This must be done in two steps because of numbers like 700.00
    std::size_t pos1 = str.find_last_not_of("0");
    if(pos1 != std::string::npos)
        str.erase(pos1+1);

    std::size_t pos2 = str.find_last_not_of(".");
    if(pos2 != std::string::npos)
        str.erase(pos2+1);

    return str;
}


static void test_string_conversion(const std::string& str)
{
    assert( to_string( atof(str.c_str()) ) == str );
}


int main(void)
{
    test_string_conversion( "1.5203" );
    test_string_conversion( "-1.025" );
    test_string_conversion( "3.1415" );
    test_string_conversion( "-38271" );
    test_string_conversion( "0.8382" );
    test_string_conversion( "-0.8382" );
    test_string_conversion( "7" );
    test_string_conversion( "-3" );
    test_string_conversion( "0.0000024" );
    test_string_conversion( "7300000000" );
}
```

Comment: nice approach - I will throw some more reasonable tests at your implementation later and comment/accept after confirmation...

Comment: Good idea. The "remove padding" code should probably be in its own function or method.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is std::fixed

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main()
{
   std::cout << std::fixed << 1.5203 << "\n";
   std::cout << std::fixed << -1.025 << "\n";
   std::cout << std::fixed << 3.1415 << "\n";
   std::cout << std::fixed << -38271 << "\n";
   std::cout << std::fixed << 0.8382 << "\n";
   std::cout << std::fixed << -0.8382 << "\n";
   std::cout << std::fixed << 7 << "\n";
   std::cout << std::fixed << -3 << "\n";
   std::cout << std::fixed << 0.0000024 << "\n";
   std::cout << std::fixed << 7300000000 << "\n";
}

1.520300
-1.025000
3.141500
-38271
0.838200
-0.838200
7
-3
0.000002
7300000000
```

Comment: Thanks for the attempt - I have added more details to the OP.  Also, look at the outputs from this solution and compare them with the original string versions.  They differ (more so) than the implementation I have in the OP.

Comment: The trouble is your tests are tailored. What you are trying to do is pointless. You are saying I have this arbitrarily defined thing that I want that I can't actually specify exactly but I  want to write code for it. This code sort of does what I want most of the time. The standard techniques have their flaws but they have an **exact** well defined behavior. If you really want to print a double out **without** loss of precision you should be printing the hex version (its loss-less for the internal representation to and from string). The decimal version is really exact (unless it ends in a 5).

Answer (score 0):

`std::sprintf()` isn't a bad choice (it's amazingly fast), but if you don't want exponentials, use `std::sprintf("%f",...)` instead.

Other choices include:

- [`Boost::format`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/format/doc/format.html)
- `std::ostringstream` or one of the other streams. You said you knew about `std::fixed` but there are other format modifiers such as [`setprecision`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setprecision) and [`setf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/setf) that may be necessary to get the format right.

Comment: Part of the headache for the `%f` route is having to deal with `setprecision` and `setf` - without setting them explicitly in `%f` or in `std::ostringstream`, I will not get the original string back (with the test cases I have in the code).  Perhaps I can improve the clarity of the code by calculating the correct '%x.yf' string somehow from double and just sprintf'ing it?

Comment: Unfortunately, there's not an easy way to calculate the "right" number of decimal places to use. The standard for floating-point numbers stores them as binary, and very few numbers have an exact binary representation. In most cases you can't round-trip. So the last significant digit is almost certainly going to be off.

Comment: Excellent point.  I agree that there will be edge cases, due to floating point precision, which are bound to fail (the conversions are lossy).  However, it would be nice to get correct answers to cases one step from the edge.  In fact, in my true use case, I am dealing with `std::decimal::decimal64` to avoid exactly those floating point issues, but even in that code, I still need to do this same conversion because there is no function to get the coefficient and exponent back from  `std::decimal::decimal64`!